# How can I associate an existing nested resource on create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-forms

I have this model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_images, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_images, allow_destroy: true
end
```

I create a bunch of ProductImage models via ajax before saving a new Product. The ajax creates form inputs for the ProductImage :id, :featured and :_destroy attributes on product_images_attributes and I correctly see these params in my log:

```
"product" => {"name" => "Test", "product_images_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"112", "featured" => "true", "_destroy"=>""}}}
```

In my controller I'm doing this in #create:

```
@product = Product.new(params.require(:product).permit!)
@product.save
```

When passing in those params I get this error when I try to assign the params:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find ProductImage with ID=112 for Product with ID=)
```

The database shows that ProductImage with ID=112 exists with product_id=null as expected.

It all works when updating an existing Product of course.

How do I associate existing ProductImages with a new record on create using standard rails methods?

Comment: Can you share the complete error log in the question.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/galatians/7d3089cadec1edfc4303

Comment: How do you update an existing product with a product image?

Comment: Why did you create `ProductImage` (child record) without an associate `Product`(parent record) in the first place?

Comment: Kirti - because it's an ajax upload so the user can see a preview before the submit the form and I want the images to persist across Product validation failure.

Comment: emaillenin - @product.update_attributes(params.require(:product).permit!)

Answer (score -1):

`nested_attributes` is not the way I recommend. It's very contreniant. I suggest to use [form objects](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects).

You can do something like this :

```
class ProductCreation
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :product_name, :product_image_ids

  def save
    images = product_image_ids.map {|id| Image.find(id) }
    product = Product.new(name: product_name)
    product.images = images
    product.save
  end
end
```

And use `ProductCreation` in your controllers and your views.

Comment: That looks interesting. Can I use fields_for with this to help generate my nested forms for each ProductImage? I'm not just assigning ids, I have :featured and :_destroy params that I'd like to apply to each ProductImage as well.

Comment: Yes you can. The inclusion of `ActiveModel::Model` allow you to have the same interface than a normal ActiveRecord model.